# Print Longest Palindromic Subsequence

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am able to print the length of  longest Palindromic subsequence correctly.But i am not able to print the string correctly.
Here is the complete question
https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-palindromic-subsequence/

> Input: s = "bbbab" Output: 4 Explanation: One possible longest
> palindromic subsequence is "bbbb".

My complete solution is https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/752148076/

```
      print(s); //print the solution .But doesnt give correct answer.Below is the code snippet.
```

Print() function gives output as "bb" for s = "bbbab".Correct would to print bbbb

```
//use this function for printing dp array!
    public void print(String str) {
       
        int x = 0,
        y = str.length() - 1; 
     //   int ans=4;
        String palindromicSubsequence="";
        
        while (x <= y) {
            if (str.charAt(x) == str.charAt(y)) {
               palindromicSubsequence= palindromicSubsequence + str.charAt(x);
                 ++x;
                --y;
            } else if ( memo[x + 1][ y] > memo[x][y - 1] ) {
                ++x;
            } else {
                --y;
            }
                
        }
            System.out.println("String is " + palindromicSubsequence );
        

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `x` is not equal to `y`, you'll have to add the character twice in the palindrome.

As the palindrome is constructed from the outside inwards, it will be easier to do this with two strings instead of one:

```java
    String left = "", right = "";
    
    while (x < y) { // Treat the case x == y separately
        if (str.charAt(x) == str.charAt(y)) {
            left = left + str.charAt(x);
            right = str.charAt(x) + right;
            ++x;
            --y;
        } else if (memo[x + 1][y] > memo[x][y - 1]) {
            ++x;
        } else {
            --y;
        }
    }
    if (x == y) { // The middle character
        left = left + str.charAt(x);
    }
    System.out.println("String is " + left + right);
```

Even better would be to use `StringBuffer`